# Cosa significa "senza fili di padroni"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

Nella canzone *Una donna così* di Gianluca Grignani trovo “senza fili di padroni”:

> E poi sei bella,
> Dio se sei bella
> sei tanto bella che neanche tu lo sai
> una donna senza inibizioni
> **senza fili di padroni**
> gli occhi un poco lucidi, sei bella

Cosa significa "senza fili di padroni"?

Comment: Mi è piaciuta la tua spiegazione. Traduco canzoni italiane in portoghese per il mio sito web. Credo di poter dire che "senza fili di padroni" è "totalmente indipendente" o totalmente libera.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Potresti scriverlo come risposta, per favore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

È una metafora (abbastanza brutta in verità, ma è mia opinione) per dire che è una donna libera, senza padroni che la tengono con fili come si fa con i burattini.

Almeno è questa la mia immediata lettura, ma non vedo altri significati, visto anche il contesto e che immediatamente prima dice 'senza inibizioni'.

Comment: Penso che la traduzione sia stata buona, Vedi nel film ho incluso anche una burattina. https://musicasitalianas.com/unadonnacosi.php

Comment: Ho visto il video, molto carino! Un bel sito il tuo per imparare l'italiano senza annoiarsi.

Comment: Ho visto qualche altra traduzione sul tuo sito, belle!

Comment: Grazie mille :-)